# Postgresql Synchronous and Asynchronous replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I've never setup streaming replication before and was unsure if the following setup is possible with the latest postgres:

- I have two data centers, with two dedicated database servers in each.
- One data center is the main center and runs all our applications, this is where we want Postgres running with synchronous streaming replication between master and slave.
- The remote data center exists for disaster recovery, and we want the main data center Postgres instances to asynchronously replicate to the remote data center.

Is the above scenario possible?  Having Master1 and Slave1 replicate synchronously in one data center, and then having Asynchronous replication between Master1 and Slave2/Slave3 which are hosted in a remote data center?

Answer (score 1):

Sure this is a scenario that is quite common and should work. I am not ware of if it works out of the box. But there are additional modules for the PostgreSQL that enables using synchronized and asynchronous replication being used simultaniously. In the end it works but I am not sure if you wont need an additional replication module.

There was also additional work being done in 9.2 and 9.3